# Assign value of column if exists in the dataframe in a case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to apply a case_when statement in a mutate(across()), as follows :

```
across(.cols = c("LIB_TOT_1", "LIB_TAT_2"), .fns = ~ case_when(
      CONDITION== "VERIF" ~ stringr::str_extract(., "(?<=\\()[^)(]+(?=\\))"),
      TRUE ~ get(paste0(stringr::str_remove(gsub('_[[:digit:]]+', '',cur_column()),'LIB_'),"_SCORE"))
```

This code above assigns as a value the number contained in the parenthesis of the LIB_ variables, and the final variable name created is written for example as : "TOT_SCORE".

The struggle here is that for some columns, the variable already exists in a previous step, and I want to keep the original value is the condition is not respected.
So, in the `"TRUE~"` step, I'd like to put a tryCatch() function or something to assign a default value if an error is encountered ( like the variable does not exist in the dataframe). So it would be something as :

```
across(.cols = c("LIB_TOT_1", "LIB_TAT_2"), .fns = ~ case_when(
      CONDITION== "VERIF" ~ stringr::str_extract(., "(?<=\\()[^)(]+(?=\\))"),
      TRUE ~ tryCatch(get(paste0(stringr::str_remove(gsub('_[[:digit:]]+', '',cur_column()),'LIB_'),"_SCORE")),error=function(e) return(NA))
```

But this code produces an error :

> Error during wrapup: badly formed function expression

Thank you very much

Comment: Please post some reproducible data and the expected output